# BASH: print output on one line

Tags: bash

I've got this simple script below to stream compressed MySQL dumps to Amazon S3 bucket in parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMIT_COUNT=0
COMMIT_LIMIT=2

for i in $(cat list.txt); do

        echo "$i "

        mysqldump -B $i | bzip2 -zc | gof3r put -b s3bucket -k $i.sql.bz2 &


        (( COMMIT_COUNT++ ))

        if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -eq ${COMMIT_LIMIT} ]; then
        COMMIT_COUNT=0
        wait
        fi

done

if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -gt 0 ]; then
        wait
fi
```

The output looks like this:

```
database1 
database2 
duration: 2.311823213s
duration: 2.317370326s
```

Is there a way to print this on one line for each dump?

```
database1 - duration: 2.311823213s
database2 - duration: 2.317370326s
```

The `echo -n` switch doesn't help in this case.

**EDIT: Wed May  6 15:17:29 BST 2015**

I was able to achieve expected results based on accepted answer:

```
echo "$i -" $(mysqldump -B $i| bzip2 -zc | gof3r put -b s3bucket -k $i.sql.bz2 2>&1) &
```

- however a command that is running in a subshell is not returning exit status to a parent shell because it's running in parallel so I'm not able to verify if it succeed or failed.

Comment: Try remove the ampersand `&` at the end of `mysqldump ..` command.

Comment: Replace `echo "$i "` by `echo -n "$i "`.

Comment: Consult the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) for the correct way to iterate over a file line-by-line.

Comment: Sub-shells report error status. You just lose that because of the "wrapping" `echo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for all your help but I think I've finally found an optimal solution for this.

Basically I used `xargs` to format the output so each entry (dump name + duration time) is on one line. I also added the job spec to `wait` command to get the exit status:

[man bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

> wait [n ...]
>       Wait for each specified process and return its termination status. Each n may be a process ID or a job specification; if a job spec is
>   given, all processes in that job's pipeline are waited for. If n is
>   not given, all currently active child processes are waited for, and
>   the return status is zero. If n specifies a non-existent process or
>   job, the return status is 127. Otherwise, the return status is the
>   exit status of the last process or job waited for.

Test:

```
# sh -c 'sleep 5; exit 1' &
[1] 29970
# wait; echo $?
0
# sh -c 'sleep 5; exit 1' &
[1] 29972
# wait $(jobs -p); echo $?
1
```

Final script:

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMIT_COUNT=0
COMMIT_LIMIT=2


while read -r i; do

    mysqldump -B $i | bzip2 -zc | gof3r put -b s3bucket -k $i.sql.bz2 |& xargs -I{} echo "${DB} - {}" &

    (( COMMIT_COUNT++ ))

    if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -eq ${COMMIT_LIMIT} ]; then
        COMMIT_COUNT=0
        wait $(jobs -p)
    fi

done < list.txt

if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -gt 0 ]; then
     wait $(jobs -p)
fi

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
     echo "ERROR: Backups failed"
     exit 1
fi
```

Comment: The problem with using `wait` this way is contained in the sentence `Otherwise, the return status is the exit status of the last process or job waited for.`. Waiting on more than one job will only get you **one** exit status and it will be the exit status of the last job to finish. (Also `$(cat list.txt)` there is pointless just use `< list.txt`.)

Comment: Yes, this is true do you know how to overcome this problem so it will exit immediately on failure?

Comment: No, I don't. Not if you run them in the background in parallel.

Answer (score 7):

I think this command will do what you want:

```
echo "$i -" `(mysqldump -B $i | bzip2 -zc | gof3r put -b s3bucket -k $i.sql.bz2) 2>&1` &
```

Or, use `$()` in place of backticks :

```
echo "$i -" $( (mysqldump -B $i| bzip2 -zc | gof3r put -b s3bucket -k $i.sql.bz2) 2>&1 ) &
```

The `echo` command will wait for `mysqldump ..` result to finish before try to print together with `$i`.  The sub-shell `( … )` and error redirection `2>&1` ensure that error messages go into the echoed output too.  The space after the `$(` is necessary because `$((` without a space is a different special operation — an arithmetic expansion.

Comment: Thanks for your help, do you know a solution to my query from updated: `EDIT: Wed May 6 15:17:29 BST 2015`?

Comment: If the output from that mysqldump command contains important internal whitespace (not newlines but spacing whitespace) this will lose that spacing. If the output ever contains shell metacharacters this will also trigger globbing/etc. on the output. This isn't a good solution. Catch the output and strip newlines specifically if that's the desired goal.

Comment: @EtanReisner If you want to preserve whitespace, this can be done by moving the second double quote to the end of the command (before ampersand).

Comment: That would preserve newlines in the mysql output which the OP appeared to *explicitly* not want. (I have no idea if the OP would want newlines from the command output should there be any or not but the newlines they did have they didn't want. And yes, that's what you *should* do instead of this comparatively unsafe and relatively incorrect quoting.

Comment: @EtanReisner I think the newline that is not wanted by OP is not caused by the mysql command. Rather it is because the echo command was run foreground while mysql command was run background but taking quite long time to finish (2 seconds).

Comment: Yes, the newline they don't want isn't caused by mysql but the implication is that they want the results all on one line. So I extrapolated to the fact that **if** mysqldump happened to return multiple lines they wouldn't want those either but that may not have been correct.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on your answer, to exit the script immediately upon failure, you have to save the pids of the background processes in an array. In your while loop add `pids[COMMIT_COUNT]=$!` after the `mysqldump` command.

Then you could write a function to loop over all these pids, and exit if one of them failed:

```
wait_jobs() {
    for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
        wait ${pid}
        if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "ERROR: Backups failed"
            exit 1
        fi
    done
}
```

Call this function instead of `wait $(jobs -p)` in the script.

### Notes

You can replace the pids array with `jobs -p` in the for loop, but then you will not get the pids of jobs that completed before the call to the loop.

The `wait_jobs()` function above cannot be used in a subshell, the `exit 1` call will only terminate the subshell then.

---

The complete script:

```
#!/bin/bash

COMMIT_COUNT=0
COMMIT_LIMIT=2

wait_jobs() {
    for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do
        wait ${pid}
        if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "ERROR: Backups failed"
            exit 1
        fi
    done
}

while read -r i; do

    mysqldump -B $i | bzip2 -zc | gof3r put -b s3bucket -k $i.sql.bz2 |& xargs -I{} echo "${DB} - {}" &
    # save the pid of the background job so we can get the
    # exit status with wait $pid later
    pids[COMMIT_COUNT]=$!

    (( COMMIT_COUNT++ ))

    if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -eq ${COMMIT_LIMIT} ]; then
        COMMIT_COUNT=0
        wait_jobs
    fi

done < list.txt

wait_jobs
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your additional question about exit status, let me write another answer. Because `$()` will run a subshell, I don't think it is possible to return the exit status to the main shell like normal command would. But it is possible to write the exit status to a file to be examined later. Please try command below. It will create file called `status-$i.txt` containing two lines. One is for `mysqldump`, the other for `gof3r`.

```
e="status-$i.txt"
echo -n > $e

echo "$i -" $( \
      ( mysqldump -B $i 2>&1; echo m=$? >> $e ) \
    |   bzip2 -zc \
    | ( gof3r put -b s3bucket -k $i.sql.bz2 2>&1; echo g=$? >> $e ) \
) &
```

You may also need to clean-up all `status-*.txt` files at the start of your script.

Answer (score 0):

I would make separate function to control all the process and then run this function in background instead of running mysqldump itself.

By doing this you will have several processes running simultaneously and at the same time you'll have control over mysqldump as it was run synchronously

```
#!/bin/bash

do_job(){
    param=$1
    echo job $param started... >&2  # Output to stderr as stdout is grabbed
    sleep $[$RANDOM/5000]
    echo $RANDOM  # Make some output
    [ $RANDOM -ge 16383 ]  # Generate exit code
}

control_job() {
    param=$1
    output=`do_job $param`
    exit_code=$?
    echo $1 printed $output and exited with $exit_code
}

JOBS_COUNT=0
JOBS_LIMIT=2

for i in database1 database2 database3 database4; do

    control_job $i &

    (( JOBS_COUNT++ ))

    if [ $JOBS_COUNT -ge $JOBS_LIMIT ]; then
        (( JOBS_COUNT-- ))
        wait -n 1  # wait for one process to exit
    fi

done

wait  # wait for all processes running
```

Here `do_job` is used in place of your mysqldump pipline.
BTW, there's a small improvement here. You probably do not want to wait for all spawned processes when you've reached the limit. It will be enough to wait for arbitrary one. That's what `wait -n 1` does

Answer (score 0):

You try to do parallelization with your script. I'd recommend not to re-invent the wheel but to use a tried and tested tool: GNU parallel. The tutorial is huge: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

It has a different options for jobs that return with exit value != 0: abort on the first error or continue working till the end.

One of the advantages of GNU parallel to the script of the OP is that it immediately starts the third job as soon as the first one is finished.

Comment: I use CentOS and unfortunately I can't install software that is not available in official repos.

Comment: Maybe you'll find something here: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#DIFFERENCES-BETWEEN-GNU-Parallel-AND-ALTERNATIVES

Answer (score -3):

untested, etc.

```
#!/bin/sh

COMMIT_COUNT=0
COMMIT_LIMIT=2

_dump() {
  # better use gzip or xz. There's no benefit using bzip2 afaict
  output="$(mysqldump -B "$1" | bzip2 -zc | gof3r put -b s3bucket -k "$1.sql.bz2" 2>&1)"
  [ "$?" != 0 ] && output="failed"
  printf "%s - %s\n" "$1" "$output"
}

while read i; do
  _dump "$i" &

  (( COMMIT_COUNT++ ))

  if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -eq ${COMMIT_LIMIT} ]; then
    COMMIT_COUNT=0
    wait
  fi
done < list.txt

wait
```